# facebook reactions request on posts return empty array

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying with the new facebook sdk (V 5.0) to get the number of reactions on posts from my facebook page
but when I execute the request it returns me an empty array for reactions key
But When I execute the same request on Graph facebook explorer It works, it return me the summary of reactions on each posts

This my code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookApp;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

$fb = new Facebook([
    'app_id' => '1795766XXX',
    'app_secret' => 'e6b0d137adf110e089d9eeXXXX',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
    'default_access_token' => 'EAACjUvPz1UUBAFMlFb5CQzsRx0jYUCZCIIYddqUtyXXX',
    ]);


$data = $fb->get('/252613XX/posts?fields=id,reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count)');
$posts = $data->getGraphEdge(); 
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($posts->asArray());
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output:

```
array(25) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(30) "252613xxxx_101568062385xxxx"
        ["reactions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(30) "25261330xxx_1015680576642xxxx"
        ["reactions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(30) "25261330xxx_1015680568030xxx"
        ["reactions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    }
    [3]=>
    array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(30) "2526133xxx_1015680571755xxx"
        ["reactions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    }
    [4]=>
    array(2) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(30) "2526133xxx_101568058112xxx"
        ["reactions"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
    }
```

And I don't know how to solve my problem

UPDATE code :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

use Facebook\Facebook;
use Facebook\FacebookApp;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;


    $fb = new Facebook([
        'app_id' => 'XXXX',
        'app_secret' => 'XXXX',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v3.2',
        'default_access_token' => 'xxx',
      ]);


    $data = $fb->get('/XXX/posts?fields=id,reactions.limit(0).summary(total_count)&since=1548603879&until=1553701479&limit=100');

    $posts = $data->getGraphObject();
    //$posts = $data->getDecodedBody();

    $all_posts = array();
    $all_post_info = array();

    if($fb->next($posts)){  

        $posts_array = $posts->asArray();
        $all_posts = array_merge($posts_array, $all_posts);
        while($posts = $fb->next($posts)){
            echo '<pre>';
            var_dump($posts);
            echo '</pre>';
            die();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I don’t see you acquiring an access token anywhere, so this should fall back to your app access token, whereas in Graph API Explorer it likely uses your user token by default.

Comment: Not sure to what extent you should be able to still get reactions in the first place though, because https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.2/object/reactions says, _“A User or Page can only query their own reactions. Other Users' or Pages' reactions are unavailable due to privacy concerns.”_

Comment: @04FS I am using a permanent access token , I am able to get share count for example but for comment count and reactions count  I am not

Comment: Permanent or not is surely not the issue here, if anything, then what _kind_ of token.

Comment: it is a page acces token , if I use getDecodedBody() method I am able to get the reactions count but I can't use the next() method for paginate .... I have to use getGraphEdge() :(

Comment: Well then use both …? `$foo = $data->getDecodedBody(); $bar = $data->getGraphEdge();`

Comment: the problem is I can only use next() method with getGraphEdge() so I have to parse the result that getGraphEdge() return and I have an empty array for reactions

Comment: Again, what is stopping you from using both?

Comment: I have updated my code maybe you can see more cleary where my problem is

Comment: In not realizing that you could use a different variable name for `//$posts = $data->getDecodedBody();` …?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it yet?

Comment: yes you have to use GraphNode instead of GraphEdge